# Shared option-like serializable type with C/C++

Tags: rust, serde

I'm writing a rust library, and I have a struct (only my culprit field shown here). In many cases, I have actual serializable structs or other data being assigned to `my_field`, but occasionally I will have no data, and therefore want to assign `null` or no item.

I attempted to do this by returning like this (in functions that create these message structs): `Message<[u8; 0]>`, and i have ffi functions that return this type, which translates to `Message<uint8_t[0]>` as a return type for those functions in the generated header file (using [cbindgen](https://github.com/eqrion/cbindgen)).

But, compiling a C++ program with array of size 0 gives the warning:

> the size of an array must be greater than 0

What rust type / technique can I use to get around this? `*const u8` is not serializable, `Option` does not exist in C++

```rs
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Message<T: Serialize> {
    pub my_field: T
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "C/C++". `std::optional` very much exists in C++. I have no idea if rust makes use of it.

Comment: cbindgen [knows](https://github.com/eqrion/cbindgen/blob/master/docs.md#supported-types) what an `Option<&T>` is (and iirc just converts it to a possibly null raw pointer), but I think it doesn't handle `Option` in the general case or convert it to `std::optional`.

Comment: @Caesar it generates a struct Option, but with no body. If i add a body or not, serializing generates an empty byte with value 0 in the place of a `None`... I need no byte to be present

Comment: @Caesar also, if i write an empty option struct in my generated header, the field after `my_field` gets reset to 0

Comment: @t348575 I see, you want to say "No data" at type level, but `Option<[T; 0]>` would still have two possible values, not one. Maybe `()` works? The docs [say](https://github.com/eqrion/cbindgen/blob/master/docs.md#std-types) that cbindgen snips fields with that type. Btw what format do you serialize to?

Comment: @Caesar serialize to raw bytes (bincode)

Comment: @Caesar `()` generates `Message` without specifying template type in the header...

Comment: All right, one last idea: Use your own zero-sized type. `#[repr(C)] pub struct Nil;`. The derived serializer [seems to](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ba8437332f00eb69e11611117edc1483) generate no bytes for it, but I have no idea what cbindgen will do.

Comment: @Caesar already tried and it doesn't work, because the struct `Nil` has some space in C++, if i try to access any data inside my struct from C++, any fields after my_field will be missaligned (because `Nil` takes up space in C++) and therefore all those fields will be corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are only two ways to get around this warning:

- Turn off ISO C++ warnings. Iirc, ISO C++ simply doesn't allow zero-sized structures. (The best reference I can find for this right now is [sizeof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof): "The result of sizeof is always nonzero")
- Use some custom dummy struct for `T` that has a 1 byte sized memory representation. You can still make sure that the serialized representation has 0 size by skipping all fields (or using custom de-/serializers):

```rust
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Serialize, Default)]
pub struct Nil {
    #[serde(skip)]
    _dummy: u8,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn mk_Nil() -> Nil {
    Default::default()
}
```

Comment: Ok wow this works, didn't expect an answer after this long, thanks!

Comment: I wonder if there's a more appropriate name though. `Empty` or `Void` or `Nothing` or `Tuple0` or something…

Answer (score 0):

Because type trait `Deserialize` is implemented on all types `Option<T>` given `T` implement `Deserialize`, you can use `Option<T>` to capture optional data. You can see documentation [here](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.145/serde/trait.Deserialize.html#impl-Deserialize%3C%27de%3E-for-Option%3CT%3E)

```
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Message<T: Serialize> {
    pub my_field: Option<T>
}
```

Comment: But then my cbindgen header will show return types with `Option` which dont exist in c++...

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your question carefully. I thought you only need to work with Rust.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Message<Option<&u8>>`:

`lib.rs`:

```rs
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct Message<T: Serialize> {
    pub my_field: T,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn get_my_field(msg: Message<Option<&u8>>) -> u8 {
    println!("{:?}", msg);
    println!("get_field {}", serde_json::to_string(&msg).unwrap());
    let a = msg.my_field.unwrap_or(&0);
    *a
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn new_message(my_field: Option<&'_ u8>) -> Message<Option<&'_ u8>> {
    Message { my_field }
}
```

`lib.h` generated by `cbindgen`:

```cpp
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ostream>
#include <new>

template<typename T>
struct Message {
  T my_field;
};

extern "C" {

uint8_t get_my_field(Message<const uint8_t*> msg);

Message<const uint8_t*> new_message(const uint8_t *my_field);

} // extern "C"
```

`main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <lib.h>

int main()
{
    Message<const uint8_t *> msg;
    msg.my_field = NULL;
    printf("%d\n", get_my_field(msg));
    const uint8_t my_field = 1;
    msg.my_field = &my_field;
    printf("%d\n", get_my_field(msg));

    auto msg2 = new_message(NULL);
    printf("%d\n", get_my_field(msg2));

    auto msg3 = new_message(&my_field);
    printf("%d\n", get_my_field(msg3));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Message { my_field: None }
get_field {"my_field":null}
0
Message { my_field: Some(1) }
get_field {"my_field":1}
1
Message { my_field: None }
get_field {"my_field":null}
0
Message { my_field: Some(1) }
get_field {"my_field":1}
1
```